# Javascript bookmarklet (Firefox) to click specific button on about:memory page

Tags: javascript, button, firefox, bookmarklet

I'd like my bookmarklet to open `about:memory` and click the `Minimize memory usage` button.

Or instead I'd like to execute the underlying function directly, but somehow when I tried, I couldn't directly call this function from the bookmarklet or console.

When I inspect the button, it leads to:
chrome://global/content/aboutMemory.js:543:14

Function:
doMMU()

I tried the method with `getElementsByName` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822931/8007479) but there's just an uncaught error thrown.

I don't even get the message that no button was found.

Seems as if about:memory isn't really treated the same as other loaded pages/documents.

Comment: Had a partial success with the following. I can run the following from the console and it runs the equivalent of the doMMU function (I basically copied what's in the function) without any error and I can see the RAM usage drop. `javascript: (() => {var emptyFunction = function() { return undefined; }; let gMgr = Cc["@mozilla.org/memory-reporter-manager;1"].getService(Ci.nsIMemoryReporterManager); gMgr.minimizeMemoryUsage(() => emptyFunction()); })();` The problem is: when I run exactly this from a bookmarklet, I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cc is not defined`. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: It appears that in the bookmarklet context `Cc` is not defined unlike on the browser console where it contains `Components.classes`. When I add `let Cc = Components.classes` in the bookmarklet I get basically the same error.